# How to replace outliers with NA having a particular range of values in R?

Tags: r, replace, range, lapply, outliers

I have climate data and I'm trying to replace outliers with `NA`. 
I'm not using `boxplot(x)$out` is because I have a range of values to be considered to compute the outlier.

```
temp_range <- c(-15, 45)
wind_range <- c(0, 15)
humidity_range <- c(0, 100)
```

My dataframe looks like this

[df with outliers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vYjR6.png)

(I highlighted values that should be replaced with NA according to ranges.)

So `temp1` and `temp2` outliers must be replaced to `NA` according to `temp_range`, `wind`'s outliers should be replaced to `NA` according to `wind_range` and finally `humidity`'s outliers must be replaced to `NA` according to `humidity_range`.

Here is what I've got:

```
df <- read.csv2("http://pastebin.com/raw/vwqBu2M5", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

df[,2:5] = apply(df[,2:5], 2, function(x) as.numeric(x))

#Ranges
temp_range <- c(-15, 45)
wind_range <- c(0, 15)
humidity_range <- c(0, 100)

#Function to detect outlier
in_interval <- function(x, interval){
  stopifnot(length(interval) == 2L)
  interval[1] <= x & x <= interval[2]
}


#Replace outliers according to temp_range
cols <- c('temp1', 'temp2')
df[, cols] <- lapply(df[, cols], function(x) {

  x[in_interval(x, temp_range)==FALSE] <- NA
  x
})
```

I'm doing the last part of code (the replacement) for every range. Is there a way to simplify it so I can avoid a lot of repetition?

Last thing, let's say `cols <- c('wind')` this  throws me a warning and replaces the whole **wind** column with a constant.

```
Warning message:
In `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, , cols, value = list(23.88, 23.93,  :
  provided 10 variables to replace 1 variables
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do it more dynamically, use a dictionnary: a dataframe with outlier value associate to each variable.

Here I create it in R, but it would be more practical to have it in csv so you can edit it easily.

```
df <- read.csv2("http://pastebin.com/raw/vwqBu2M5", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

df[,2:5] = apply(df[,2:5], 2, function(x) as.numeric(x))


df_dict <- data.frame(variable = c("temp1", "temp2", "wind", "humidity"), 
                       out_low = c(-15, -15, 0, 0), 
                       out_high =c(45, 45, 15, 100))

for (var in df_dict$variable) {

  df[[var]][df[[var]] < df_dict[df_dict$variable == var, ]$out_low | df[[var]] > df_dict[df_dict$variable == var, ]$out_high] <- NA

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're making it more complicated than it needs to be. You can use logical vectors to selectively replace only certain values in a variable:

```
df <- read.csv2("http://pastebin.com/raw/vwqBu2M5", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

df[,2:5] = apply(df[,2:5], 2, function(x) as.numeric(x))

#Ranges
temp_range <- c(-15, 45)
wind_range <- c(0, 15)
humidity_range <- c(0, 100)

df$temp1[df$temp1 < temp_range[1] | df$temp1 > temp_range[2]] <- NA
df$temp2[df$temp2 < temp_range[1] | df$temp2 > temp_range[2]] <- NA
df$wind[df$wind < wind_range[1] | df$wind > wind_range[2]] <- NA
df$humidity[df$humidity < humidity_range[1] | df$humidity > humidity_range[2]] <- NA
```

Basically all you're doing is taking a variable, creating a logical vector that selects only values outside of your range, and replacing those values with `NA`

That will give you the following (which doesn't quite match your image, but the numbers seem correct based on your ranges):

```
                  time temp2 wind humidity temp1
1  2006-11-22 22:00:00    NA 0.00    56.95 23.88
2  2006-11-22 23:00:00  15.5 0.00    58.21 23.93
3  2006-11-23 00:00:00    NA   NA    62.95 23.81
4  2006-11-23 01:00:00  12.0 0.30    70.15    NA
5  2006-11-23 02:00:00  35.0 0.07    76.46 21.63
6  2006-11-23 03:00:00  12.0 0.79       NA 21.81
7  2006-11-23 04:00:00  35.0 0.50    69.11 21.04
8  2006-11-23 05:00:00  14.0 0.37    71.86 20.32
9  2006-11-23 06:00:00  -9.0 0.26    70.97 20.50
10 2006-11-23 07:00:00    NA 0.03    78.02    NA
```

Comment: I updated the image, results should look like your output. Is it possible to do the first and second replacement lines in a lapply? They look quite similar and I've posted just a sample, I have more columns based on `temp_range` so this replacement lines amount will grow and I'm wishing to do it more dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a function,

```
check_inRange <- function(col, range) {
   df[col] >= range[1] & df[col] <= range[2]
}
```

and then for every column, you can call this function as

```
df[!check_inRange("temp1", temp_range), "temp1"] <- NA
df[!check_inRange("temp2", temp_range), "temp2"] <- NA
df[!check_inRange("wind", wind_range), "wind"] <- NA
df[!check_inRange("humidity", humidity_range), "humidity"] <- NA
```

This would replace all the values in respective columns which are out of range to `NA`

Comment: In `check_inRange` function the condition must be `df[col] >= range[1] & df[col] <= range[2]` so 0 is not replaced since it's not an outlier in column `wind` (see attached image)

Comment: @Martin okay..updated the answer. Also in the image in `temp2` column 35 should not be highlighted. As it is in the range. (-15, 45) Isn't it?

Comment: You're right. Updated. Btw nice solution. That function works like a charm but looks a bit hardcoded if I'd have another data frame. I'll work on it since I could use the same function to first plot outliers and condition the colors and and after that replace them with NA.

Comment: Well, if you have different dataframes , you can pass the dataframe into the function parameter as well. Something like `check_inRange <- function(col, range, df) `