# Replacing outliers with NA in R data frame

Tags: r, boxplot, outliers

I have some data in R data frame. I have to remove outliers from it. I am using boxplot function to remove outliers from it. Though this method removes complete row.

How can I modify it to replace the outliers with NA so I can save the data ?

Here is my code:

```
outliers <- boxplot(outlier_H_rem$var1, plot=FALSE)$out
if(length(outliers) == 0)
  { outlier_H_rem1<-outlier_H_rem
  boxplot(outlier_H_rem1$var1)} else { 
  outlier_H_rem1<-outlier_H_rem[-which(outlier_H_rem$var1 %in% outliers),]
  var1<-outlier_H_rem1$var1}
  boxplot(outlier_H_rem1$var1)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40210424/how-to-replace-outliers-with-na-having-a-particular-range-of-values-in-r

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to replace outliers with NA having a particular range of values in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40210424/how-to-replace-outliers-with-na-having-a-particular-range-of-values-in-r)

Comment: See also: `rAverage::outlier.replace`

Comment: while you can remove outliers, it is worth considering if that is the most appropriate course of action if outliers are actually real values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
outlier_H_rem1 <- outlier_H_rem

outliers <- boxplot(outlier_H_rem$var1, plot=FALSE)$out

outlier_H_rem1$var1[outlier_H_rem1$var1 %in% outliers] <- NA
```

With sample data as:

```
outlier_H_rem <- data.frame(var1 = c(runif(100), 42, 17, 33))
```